# Google Cloud Storage API Error -- tried to access method com.google.com.base.Stopwatch

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've been using GCS for several months for temporary storage during some tasks.  I've recently added a bunch of new writes and reads and get the following error (since upgrading to GAE 1.9.4).  I've tried several different RetryParams instantiations (including DefaultInstance) to no avail.  This same code used to work.

```
[Client]
OS: Windows 7 (6.1, x86)
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Java: Oracle Corporation (1.7.0_55)
ULC: ULC Core 2013 (Canoo RIA Suite 2013 Update 1)
Time: Fri May 02 16:12:43 MDT 2014

[Server]
OS: Linux (null, null)
Java: Google Inc. (1.7.0)

[Stacktrace]
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.<init>(RetryHelper.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:138)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace(GcsServiceImpl.java:47)
    at com.nfmc.FM.shared.nfmcUtil.gcsWrite(nfmcUtil.java:677)
    at com.nfmc.FM.shared.nfmcGAETask.schedule(nfmcGAETask.java:161)
    at com.nfmc.FM.shared.nfmcGAETask.schedule(nfmcGAETask.java:152)
    at com.nfmc.FM.shared.nfmcReport.taskReport(nfmcReport.java:127)
```

Comment: A bit more information -- everything works well on the development server.  I suspect there may be some application files that have been left around on the server that the application deployment tool in eclipse doesn't remove.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

that issue with guava lib update use 10.0.1 jar for it (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release10) it's resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.IllegalAccessError may be coming due to jar file version compatibility issue. I too faced this issue. Then, I downloaded all the jar files from a single location and the error went away.

I downloaded jars from mvnrepository which lists all dependent jar files and their versions.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.tools/appengine-gcs-client/0.4.3